# How to run a Lucene 4.9 IndexFiles?

Tags: java, eclipse, lucene

I am a Lucene newbie and I am trying to run Lucene 4.9 indexFiles on Eclipse but I got the following error for the line
 `IndexWriterConfig iwc = new IndexWriterConfig(Version.LUCENE_4_9, analyzer);` of the IndexFiles.java class from `org.apache.lucene.demo`.

```
at org.apache.lucene.index.LiveIndexWriterConfig.<init>(LiveIndexWriterConfig.java:125)
at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriterConfig.<init>(IndexWriterConfig.java:171)
at org.apache.lucene.demo.IndexFiles.main(IndexFiles.java:92)Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A SPI class of type org.apache.lucene.codecs.Codec with name 'Lucene49' does not exist. You need to add the corresponding JAR file supporting this SPI to your classpath.The current classpath supports the following names: [SimpleText, Appending, Lucene40, Lucene3x]
at org.apache.lucene.util.NamedSPILoader.lookup(NamedSPILoader.java:109)
at org.apache.lucene.codecs.Codec.forName(Codec.java:95)
at org.apache.lucene.codecs.Codec.<clinit>(Codec.java:122)
... 3 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the lucene core jar file included and its version is 4.9. If you've just moved from an older version to 4.9, probably you are using the wrong version of the lucene jars on the **runtime environment**.

I mean you are using the correct jars on eclipse, but the runtime configuration is pointing to another jar whose version is older than 4.9.

Comment: Do you know How can I set the correct version for runtime configuration.

Comment: The error message says "_The current classpath supports the following names: [SimpleText, Appending, **Lucene40, Lucene3x**]_"
I don't know which tools you are using, but it looks like it contains Lucene 4.0. So check your classpath.

Comment: One more detail if you are using tomcat, open tomcat configurations and see which dependency jars are included there. Otherwise I would suggest you create a new simple project, add lucene v4.9 jars and check if the error still exists.